# Organise a many to many relationship in MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, many-to-many

I'm building an ecommerce Rails application, and I want to create a relationship between **Products** and **Users**.

Users can "favorite" many products (and products can be favorited by users).

Users have a "history" about the products they saw.

In SQL databases, I know I can create, for example, a **History** table and put the product_id and user_id. And a **Favorited** table with also product_id and user_id.

But in MongoDB, how can I build this relationships?

I read this blog post: http://blog.markstarkman.com/blog/2011/09/15/mongodb-many-to-many-relationship-data-modeling/ and realized that I can create an array of products inside **Users** collection, and an array of users inside **Products** collection. But I don't know how to set what is the favorited product and the history product inside **Users** collection.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

**Thought**: I'm thinking in create two models (ProductFavorited and ProductHistory) inheriting from Product model/collection and use it inside users collection.

Answer (score 1):

The best data model in MongoDB is one that fits your application use.

So the questions to ask are "When are you going to see these favorited Products? How are they displayed?" and "When are you going to see this History? How is it displayed?"

Some possible answers and advice might be:

> "A user will be able to click a menu item labeled 'Favorites' and see
>   a list of Products that they have favorited."
>
> Then it makes sense to store the information you plan to show in a
>   `favorites` array on the User document. Or if you expect the User
>   document to be growing too large, a separate `favorites` collection
>   with just a user_id as `_id` and then just the array of favorites as
>   the only other element in the document.

Or:

> "A user will go to a Product page and see a list of other users that have favorited that Product."
>
> Then it makes sense to store it the other way with all of the users that favorited the product in the Product document. Or if you think the Product document will grow too large then in a separate collection with product_id as the `_id` and the favorited_users as an array which is the only other element in the document.

The thing to always keep in mind is how the data will be used in your application.

[Information about Data Model in MongoDB.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/)